# Url Redirect in Joomla using Htaccess

Tags: redirect, joomla

Hi i want to redirect my URL from

http://foo.example.com to http://example.com/foo

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Why not try a Joomla SEO component? E.g. sh404sef or acesef